# Header location wont work in IE, but works if I set a cookie first

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, header

I have a simple header location:

```
header("Location: http://www.domain.com/logged_in");
die();
```

This wont work in IE, but works in FF, Opera, Chrome etc...

BUT, this all works if I set a cookie first (in this case a login cookie).

What could be the prob?

I have ob_start(); on top of the page, if that might have anything to do with it...

Thanks

Comment: people often use ob (output buffering) as a hack to fix header set issues, rather than fixing it properly by appropriately structuring their code.

Comment: which version of IE, and what HTTP return message does IE give or does it simply spill the output of this current page?  And, have you just tried testing the redirect alone on a test page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you try adding these lines before the header() call and see if something changes?

```
while (ob_get_level()) 
{
    ob_end_clean();
}
```